# Trying to center image grid that keeps sticking to left

Tags: html, css, image, grid-layout

I'm trying to center the images in the page to allow the to fill up the space according to the size i set however they just stick to the left. I've tried a number of solutions and have gotten close but it did not center. To get a clear idea of what I'm looking for here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fnGwP/

Any solutions?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="view view-first">
            <img src="images/calendar-2014-web.jpg" />
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>2014 Calendar decal</h2>
                <br>
                <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                <br>
                <a href="#" class="info">Buy now</a>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="view view-first">
            <img src="images/calendar-2014-web.jpg" />
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Hover Style #1</h2>
                <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
#content {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0;

}

#main {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.view {
   width: 399px;
   height: 266px;
   margin: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 399px;
   height: 266px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

/*----------- photos ----------*/
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   width: 399px;
   height:auto;
}
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it seemed to work fine. You haven't really described what you want—center where? Within the `view` div? Works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: I want the photos to display in the center of the page. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. Try adding an image to your fiddle and tell us if that's not what you want. E.g. `<img src="http://placehold.it/399" />`

Comment: I've tried other browsers but they still sticks left. Weird that it displays fine for you. Anybody else getting a perfect grid?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P9HL2/

Comment: Problem is, it's not clear what "fine" is. It looks OK to me, but it's not clear what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Let's say the space the images have is 1000px, i would like the images to have equal spacing on the right and left side... that the grid that the images create be in the center of the page... not stuck on the left of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer, based on comment 3 below. Add these to the current styles, which is one way to center the `.view` divs in a square block of 4.

```
#main {
    text-align: center;
}

.view {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Another option would be to set a width on #main (say 820px) and then float the .view boxes.

Comment: Hey Ralph, it got me close but it started interfering with the animations that are part of each image. I think it might help if I give more detail. Here's the fiddle for more context: http://jsfiddle.net/fnGwP/

Comment: The animation looks fine to me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Imagine a square with 4 images. At each corner an image not an ugly strait row of images down the center but a grid that takes up the available space. that's what I'm trying to get. your correction got the images to center but not spread out, with spacing between each image.

Comment: O, I never would have guessed that from your question. I've updated my answer. There are various ways to do this. I've just posted on option (the easiest).

Comment: Thanks for your help Ralph, I needed to add #content {text-align: center;} to get images centered.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to get things looking like I wanted I changed the CSS to:

```
#content {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 35px 0 35px 0;
    text-align: center;

}

#main {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*----------- grid ----------*/

.view {
    clear:both;
    width: 324px;
    height: 216px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 324px;
   height: 216px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```